# How to analyze ant build output for further decision making?

Tags: java, ant

I'm writing an ant build script to run regression tests for an application. I need to run the test cases sequentially and only if the previous test run was successful. Is there a way I can look a the output of the build to decide if the next target can be called?

```
 [exec] [revBuild] RC = 1
 [exec] -------------------------------------------------
 [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 minutes 23 seconds
```

In the above output, the called application has failed. Is there a way I can search for the application return code in the build output, based on which the next ant target(to run the next test case) can be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to set the `failonerror` attribute of [the exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to true. If you do this and the executable's return status code is anything other than 0, then the buildwill fail.

Youi could also store this status code in a property using the `resultproperty` attribute, and execute some task only if this property is set (or is not set).